# list comprehension: create 2 items for each item in input list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list that is as follows:

```
list1 = ["pierre", "paul", "jacques"]
```

I would like to create a new list with 6 items that would be:

```
list2 = ["pierre", "pierre#2","paul","paul#2", "jacques", "jacques#2"]
```

I tried the following:

```
list2 = [i, "{}#2".format(i) for i in list1 ]
```

which obviously didn't work. Would anyone have a suggestion of what would work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with a nested loop:

```
[item for i in list1 for item in (i, "{}#2".format(i))]
```

The `for item in (...)` inner loop produces 2 items each time.

Comment: `itertools.chain(*zip(list1,map("{}#2".format,list1)))` ? :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley: yeah, no.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm the only one who has a hard time reading nested list-comprehensions, but I tend to avoid them like the plague<sup>1</sup>.  In this case, I'd probably use a vanilla loop:

```
lst_out = []
for item in list1:
    lst_out.extend((item, '{}#2'.format(item)))
```

Or another option is a generator function:

```
def gen(list1):
    for item in list1:
        yield item
        yield '{}#2'.format(item)
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>This isn't 100% true ... The standard nested list flattening idiom is fairly recognizable to me so I've used it once or twice.  Maybe I just need to start using them so that they become more intuitive ...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You would never do this (the other answers are all better), but as a thought exercise:

```
from itertools import chain
l = list(chain.from_iterable((x, x+'#2') for x in list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could still do your attempt (you were just missing some parentheses to create `tuple`s) and then "flatten" the tuples afterwards:

```
list2 = [(i, "{}#2".format(i)) for i in list1]
list2 = [x for y in list2 for x in y]
```

Which produces:

```
['pierre', 'pierre#2', 'paul', 'paul#2', 'jacques', 'jacques#2']
```